# How to prevent Angular/material mat-menu from closing on key-navigation (tab)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have read [How to prevent angular material mat-menu from closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967970/how-to-prevent-angular-material-mat-menu-from-closing) , which explains how to prevent Angular material mat-menu from closing on click.

However: **I cannot seem to find a way to prevent a mat-menu from closing when I press tabulator to change focus**.

Take this StackBlitz as an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ij6jbx:
it properly prevents the `mat-menu` from closing **when** the input-fields receive the focus **via mouse click**. On the other hand: if I press "tabulator" to change focus and the `username`-input-field receives the focus, the menu closes.

I would like to know how to prevent this behavior - if it's possible. I tried attaching `$event.stopPropagation();` to `(input)`, but it did not seem to do anything.

Apparently some thought has been given to this by the Angular developers according to https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2612. Sadly there does not seem to be a proper solution at the end of the issue / feature-request nor a hint about the status.

*P.s.:* I know, that the current code is not beautiful nor really smart. I was going to refactor that into its own directive once it worked for both click and key-press.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can catch `keydown` event as follows:

```
<mat-menu ...>
  <form (keydown.tab)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyfu7r?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Also, I would add `tabindex="-1"` to all clear buttons

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly the forked StackBlitz you offered does not work as expected. I would have loved to be able to use the "tab"-key to focus onto username, then upon another press to focus on password and finally "tab" to focus the log-in button (and use "return" to log in). Possibly also use the "return"-key to log in when on username or password (but that'd be a different story). **I do not want to disregard the tab-ability** if possible. I also would like to omit turning off tabindex on anything, that's normally focusable.

Comment: Actually tab-ability is working as expected. When menu is opened angular material sets focus on the `mat-menu-item` element. Next click on tab button will move it to another element that is not part of menu. Updated example.Changed `<button mat-menu-item>` to `<button class="mat-menu-item"` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyfu7r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you! The only thing missing is how to set the focus on the username? Meaning that once the menu is open, the first control (in this case the "username"-input-field) is focused. I tried `cdkFocusInitial`, but it does not work. Should I manually set the focus or is there a directive or something for that? Other than that: thank you very much.

Comment: Added `mat-menu-item` to input. Also see `app.component.css` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyfu7r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes - that's great! **Thank you!** By the way: there is no need to have `false` at the end of the `(click)`-directive, because we do not need to `preventDefault`. Also there might be a need for shift-tab-support, which one can include using `(keydown.shift.tab)="$event.stopPropagation()"` right next to `(keydown.tab)`.

Comment: Hm one thing keeps being weird... if I use `class="mat-menu-item"` instead of the `mat-menu-item`-directive, the button's appearance is same, but it does not receive focus if "tabbed" onto using the keyboard...

Comment: You can use `ma-menu-item` attribute now since `input` element will be the first focused item anyway, but i see focus on that button in my example even when use class. Maybe that's because i added `:focus` style in app.component.css

Comment: Actually there's still a problem: even if I add the `mat-menu-item`-directive properly, if I "**tab**" onto a focusable control outside the menu while the menu is open, the menu does not close for whatever reason. However: if I "**click**" outside, it does close as expected. Do you happen to have an idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: Works great. One may also want to add `(keydown.home)="$event.stopPropagation()"` and `(keydown.end)="$event.stopPropagation()"`