# How to prevent material menu from closing without user permission in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-material-6, angular-material-5

I am having a `mat-menu` containing multiple checkboxes, and I want the user to close it when he checks all types of filter he wants.

The actual behavior is when you click on anything it will be automatically closed.

I have this code:

```
<button color="warn" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-checkbox color="warn">
      By LM
    </mat-checkbox>&nbsp;
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-checkbox color="warn">
      By UN
    </mat-checkbox>&nbsp;
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I checked [this post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967970/how-to-prevent-angular-material-mat-menu-from-closing?answertab=active#tab-top) but the event didn't work.

And from the documentation, they said:

> @Output() closed: EventEmitter
>
> Event emitted when the menu is closed.

But I am not able to figure out how to use this output, and if it is even relevant to what I need.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-xznzb9).

How to prevent mat-menu from closing without the user click outside of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I checked out your stackblitz and you can do:

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
```

This will prevent it from closing.